# Help Identifying A Medieval / Fantasy Animated Cartoon Quote: "Fireball, Fly!"

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, wizards

I need help identifying a Medieval / Fantasy Animated Cartoon featuring a Wizard and (partner[s]?) He is able to cast spells; but not infinitely and his most famous ability I can remember is that he calls his spell; "Fireball, Fly!"

It's been driving me nuts for a while now and any help you can provide would be appreciated. It was most likely during the 90's or MAYBE early 2000's (But I doubt that; more likely 90's)

If I remember correctly he was a Student, but his Wizard Master Died (MAYBE NOT POSITIVE) and he had to protect something/someone....

It aired on Canadian T.V. Stations; possibly YTV or Teletoon (but could be another that I'm forgetting.)

HELP.... :(

Comment: The "Dungeons And Dragons" animated series, perhaps?

Comment: Just making sure, is it possible that it was "Firebolt". Just ruling out Harry Potter here

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is [XCALIBUR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcalibur). It's a medieval/fantasy animated cartoon featuring a wizard (and partners) who says "Fireball, fly!". The wizard is a student, and his Wizard Master gave him something to protect (the Book of Life, collected knowledge of the wizards). It aired in the early 2000s on Canadian television network YTV. Here's a still from the show:

[image: Still image of Djana and Herik]

From [this review](https://min.news/en/comics/12536dcfc99e5cb7e1a95b4d31ca6d34.html):

> The heroine Tijana's weapon is a sword, and the hero Heko's weapon is a book. Later, he met the barbarian Tara, so Heko and Tara became the heroine's partner, and the hero assists the woman. The protagonist advises the heroine when it is difficult. Although he does not know how to use a sword, he is very smart. "Fireball, fly!" This is what the male protagonist says every time he casts a spell. After all, he was also a mage. After experiencing all kinds of difficulties, the heroine finally defeated the evil Komanda, and also saved her father and country, and followed Heko to travel to the ends of the earth...

Comment: How does it match?

Comment: It's a medieval/fantasy animated cartoon featuring a wizard (and partners) who, according to the first link, says "Fireball, fly!". The wizard is a student, and his Wizard Master gave him something to protect (the Book of Life, collected knowledge of the wizards). Finally, it aired in the early 2000s on Canadian television network YTV.

Comment: Sounds like good things to include in the answer. :-D

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like dragonlance. The character is fizban.

Comment: Can you provide some quotes from a description of the book?